# shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, broadcast

```
j=np.arange(20,dtype=np.int)
site=np.ones((20,200),dtype=np.int)
sumkma=np.ones((100,20))

[sumkma[site[x],x] for x in range(20)]
```

This works, but I don't want to use for loop. When I try

```
sumkma[site[j],j]
```

I get this error:

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,200) (20,)

How to fix the error?

Comment: NumPy broadcasting aligns dimensions from right to left, not left to right.

Comment: This error is commonly caused when mixing numpy's indexing methods, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831767/9698684) for a similar case

Answer (score 13):

When accessing a numpy multi-dimensional array with other multi-dimensional arrays of integer type the arrays used for the indices need to have the same shape.

Numpy will happily broadcast, if possible - but for that to be possible the arrays need to **have the same dimensionality**, e.g. this works:

```
sumkma[site[j], j[:,np.newaxis]]
```

The `np.newaxis` results in `j[:,np.newaxis]` being two-dimensional (shape is now `(20,1)`, whereas shape of `j` is one-dimensional `(20,)`). It now has a shape that can be broadcasted to the shape of `site[j]`:

```
>>> j.shape
(20,)
>>> site[j].shape
(20,200)
>>> j[:,np.newaxis].shape
(20,1)
```

The same dimensionality for the index arrays allows numpy to broadcast them to have the same shape `(20,200)`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: j[:,np.newaxis] is equal to j.reshape(-1,1). so another answer is sumkma[site[j], j.reshape(-1,1)]