# Numpy array Indexing with other arrays yields broadcasting error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have two indexing arrays.

```
elim=range(130,240)
tlim=range(0,610)
```

The array to be indexed, `I`,  has originally shape of `(299, 3800)`

When I try to index it as follow

```
I[elim,tlim]
```

I got the following error message.

> shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (110,) (610,)

I didn't expect such errors. Could someone explain what is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well how are you expecting to index up to row 610 if the array has 299 rows? (although the error is caused by something else)

Comment: sorry, I have made a mistake in the question. Now corrected

Comment: i think you want: `my_array[130:240, :610]` (you shouldn't overwrite the std. lib's `len` function)

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to put numbers there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: With advanced indexing (lists or arrays), the index arrays `broadcast` against each other.  A (n,) array will work with a (n,) producing (n,) result.  A (n,1) will work with a (1,m) to produce a (n,m) result.  Same broadcasting rules as when adding or multiplying arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's reproduce the example with a random array of the specified shape:

```
elim=range(0,610)
tlim=range(130,240)
a = np.random.rand(299, 3800)

a[tlim, elim]
```

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (110,) (610,)

This raises an error because you're using arrays of integer indexes to index the array, and hence [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) rules will apply.
You should use slices for this example

```
a[130:240,0:610].shape
# (110, 610)
```

See [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) (NumPy indexing, is just an extension of the same concept up to ndimensional arrays.

For the cases in which you have a list of indices, not necessarily expressable as slices, you have [`np.ix_`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np.ix_&rlz=1C1CHBD_enES868ES868&oq=np.ix_&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). For more on numpy indexing, [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d) might help

```
a[np.ix_(tlim, elim)].shape
# (110, 610)
```