Dynamically build slice indexes on multiple axes
I want to extract a slice from an n-dimensional array. The slice indexes for each axes are dynamically computed and are None (=all indexes) or any ordered or unordered sequence. Therefore I thought using slice objects for each axis are a reasonable option. Furthermore, I do not know the number of axes of the n-dimensional array a priori. And the result must be in the shape given by the indexing instructions.
a = np.arange(10*8).reshape((10, 8))
slc = [slice(None)] * a.ndim
slc[0] = np.arange(3, 8)
slc[1] = np.arange(2, 4)
a[tuple(slc)]

This sample snippet should demonstrate the usage. Using only one slice object for one axis works quite fine. But using both slice objects together fails.
Edit 1:
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (2,)

Edit 2: This solves the problem
slc[0] = np.arange(3, 8)[:, None]
slc[1] = np.arange(2, 4)[None, :]

I'm grateful for any hint.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124469/shape-mismatch-indexing-arrays-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes

Show the actual error.  And the indexing tuple.  You appear to have the basic idea.

a[ [3,4,5,6,7], [2,3] ] - you tell us what's wrong with that indexing. Before you try to make a 'dynamic' indexing, learn to do regular, explicit indexing.  There aren't any slices.  Those are arrays/lists - advanced indexing.

Thanks! @hpaulj The simple indexing also doesn't work. I get the same error message I've edited within my post now. The snippet just illustrates the problem. The real computations are a little bit more complicated. At the end any series of numbers will result for the indexes.

This works for me a[tuple([slice(3,8), slice(2,4)])]

As your edit shows, broadcastability is important when using 'advanced indexing' (arrays or lists). With slices it's simpler.

@furas Thanks! Your code works because both slices have the same number of elements (indexes) and therefore they are broadcastable. In my case I don't know the length of each sequence.

It really depends on what you want to select.  One way you can get a block, the other its diagonal.  np.ix_ is also useful when asking for a block.

To create 'dynamic' indexing you have to first understand indexing itself
The most comprehensive doc page is
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html
it also links to a indexing routines page
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#routines-indexing
Your basic 2d array
In [183]: a = np.arange(10*8).reshape((10, 8))

Using a tuple of slices does basic indexing, here 5 rows, 2 columns:
In [184]: a[3:8, 2:4]
Out[184]: 
array([[26, 27],
       [34, 35],
       [42, 43],
       [50, 51],
       [58, 59]])

You can use a list of slice objects to do the same:
In [185]: idx = [slice(3,8), slice(2,4)]; a[tuple(idx)]
Out[185]: 
array([[26, 27],
       [34, 35],
       [42, 43],
       [50, 51],
       [58, 59]])

Your first mistake was that you tried to use arrays to do the indexing, not slice objects.  (OK, you initialed the list with slice(None), but replaced all elements with arrays.)
In [186]: slc = [np.arange(3,8), np.arange(2,4)]

In [187]: a[tuple(slc)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[187], line 1
----> 1 a[tuple(slc)]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (2,) 

You can't do advanced indexing without understanding numpy broadcasting:
In [188]: a[slc[0][:,None], slc[1]]
Out[188]: 
array([[26, 27],
       [34, 35],
       [42, 43],
       [50, 51],
       [58, 59]])

You can use multiple 1d arrays, but they have to match, that is, they have to broadcast.  And the result is 1d, matching those arrays.  I think of that as taking the 'diagonal' of a block:
In [190]: a[slc[0],slc[0]]
Out[190]: array([27, 36, 45, 54, 63])

The distinction between indexing a block and indexing a 'diagonal' seems to confuse wayward MATLAB programmers, where the notation is almost the direct opposite.
A handy tool for making the broadcastable arrays is np.ix_:
In [191]: np.ix_(*slc)
Out[191]: 
(array([[3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7]]),
 array([[2, 3]]))

In [192]: a[np.ix_(*slc)]
Out[192]: 
array([[26, 27],
       [34, 35],
       [42, 43],
       [50, 51],
       [58, 59]])

This and other functions/classes are listed in the indexing routines page.  Many are defined in np.lib.indexing_tricks.py file.
Here's a class instance that converts the slice notation into ranges, and concatenates:
In [193]: np.r_[3:8, 2:4]
Out[193]: array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3])

and one the converts slice notation into a tuple of slice objects:
In [194]: np.s_[3:8, 2:4]
Out[194]: (slice(3, 8, None), slice(2, 4, None))

Another class instance that expands slices into arrays:
In [195]: np.ogrid[3:8, 2:4]
Out[195]: 
[array([[3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7]]),
 array([[2, 3]])]

And a common meshgrid, which can make a similar list:
In [196]: np.meshgrid(*slc, sparse=True, indexing='ij')
Out[196]: 
[array([[3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7]]),
 array([[2, 3]])]

Studying the underlying code for functions like this may save you from 'reinventing the wheel'.

Beautiful answer.

Totally agree! Nice answer.

@hpaulj A further question regarding to your anwser: How to build the input of s_[] dynamically, e.g. from a list or array?

alist=[slice(3,8), slice(4,6), np.arange(1,4)]; np.s_[alist]?  But why?  The whole point to using np.s_ is to use the convenient 3:8 notation instead of slice(3,8).

Thanks a lot! I need to compute the indices per axes to be accessed. For e.g., indices for first axis are certain ints, for second indices maybe all and for third axis also certain ints. So, I can not directly type in the numbers within slice(). I've played a little bit around but currently I do not found a suitable solution. For e.g., in programming language R I can pass a list with indices for each axis to do.call([, c(list(array), list_of_indices)). That's a smart and fast working solution I try to adopt for Python.
